# How to rewrite this list comprehension function to a function using map?

Tags: haskell

I have this function, that counts only Uppercase letters and returns the counts of each letter
for example: the input "ABCd" gives me: [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I implemented the function using list comprehension, but the task is to write it using a map function. How do i do that?

```
counter xs = [count x xs |x<- ['A'..'Z']]
  where count x [] = 0
        count a (x:xs)
            |a == x = 1 + count a xs
            |otherwise = count a xs
```

Comment: `map f ys` is the same as `[f x | x <- ys]`. This also applies in the other direction, so you can replace the list comprehension with a `map`, as long as you define a suitable `f`.

Comment: The section of the Haskell Report on [list comprehensions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) spells out how to translate a list comprehension into more basic syntax and the `concatMap` function (defined as `concatMap f = concat . map f` in the Prelude).

Answer (score 2):

As hinted in comments, `map` takes a function to map to each element in the list. Your job is simply to design that function.

```
counter xs = map (\ch -> count ch xs) ['A'..'Z']
  where
    count _ [] = ...
    count ch (y:ys)
      | ch == y = ...
      | otherwise = ...
```